# What's the difference between "anyway vs anyways" and "a lot vs lots"?

Tags: grammar

I  have noticed that in a movie they said "anyways" and also "have  lots of time".

Why didn't they say "anyway" and "a lot"  instead of  "lots" ?

Comment: Can you add more to this?  The exact line in the movie where the character used "anyways", or any related dialogue?

Comment: There are **lots** of reasons why people use one form or the other. But equally, there **a lot** of reasons why people use one form or the other. Either way, it makes no real difference. Anyway, I think only "dialectal" New World Anglophones use ***anyways***. It's "folksy".

Comment: "Anyways" is kind of folksy, like FumbleFingers says.  But I have never heard anyone say "a lots".  What movie was this in?

Comment: I read somewhere that _anyway_ is formal and _anyways_ is informal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[Anyways](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/anyways)*** is used in U.S.A. and Canada:

> - US and Canadian a ***nonstandard word for anyway***.

***[A lot of](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Lots)*** or ***lots of***:

> - A large extent, amount, or number: *is in a lot of trouble; has lots of friends.*

The Free Dictionary